# LINQ Query on EF Core many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have the following many-to-many relationship modeled (by convention) in Entity Framework Core 5:

```
  public class Task
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    // Relationships
    public ICollection<TaskOwner> OwnersLink { get; set; }
  }

  public class TaskOwner
  {
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }

    // Relationships
    public Task Task { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
  }

  public class Owner
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // Relationships
    public ICollection<TaskOwner> TasksLink { get; set; }
  }
```

How do I construct a query using the fluent LINQ syntax (E.g. `_dbContext.Owners.Where(s => s.Id == 1);`) that will return all Tasks that don't have any Owners please?

Comment: I don't see any tricky issue here - tasks w/o owners are expressed naturally with `.Where(task => !task.OwnersLink.Any())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two answers given so far missed or ignored the fact that you have this navigation property `Task.OwnersLink`. All you have to do is check if it doesn't contain any items.

```cs
_dbContext.Tasks.Where(t => !t.OwnersLink.Any())
```

It seems a small difference, but when queries grow larger it's very easy to make an error in these unnecessary manual "joins" like `o => o.TaskId == t.Id`.

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var tasksWithoutOwner = ctx.Tasks
   .Where(x => ctx.TaskOwners.Any(y => y.TaskId == x.Id) == false);
```

Answer (score 1):

to return all Tasks that don't have any Owners try this

```
 var tasks= _dbContext.Tasks
.Where(t => !_dbContext.TaskOwners.Any(to => to.TaskId == t.Id))
.ToList();
```